# excel vba select range of a table

Tags: vba, excel

I want to select a table, it will have fixed columns(4 of them) but can have any number of rows, empty rows as well. How will I select a table range?

[image]

For example, the current selection is `B2 to E5`

How can I get this programmatically in VBA?

Comment: `lRow = Worksheets("SheetName").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row` finds the last used row in column B. With that information you should be able to write a code for this. If you got stuck or errors come back [edit] your question, add your code and ask a good and detailed question to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how you can set a reference to the Table.  You should watch: [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&index=5&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5).  It will give you a better understanding of Ranges, Worksheets and the Excel object model.

```
Dim Target As Range
With Worksheets("SheetName")
    Set Target = .Range("B2:E2", .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With
```

Comment: But what if in column `B` the last row is empty? So for example `B` has 5 rows but `C` has 6 rows?

Comment: If there isn't a single row that always has data consider using `Range("B2").CurrentRegion`.  In some cases it will return extra rows (particularly if the formatting extends past the table)  but it will usually work correctly.  Alternatively, you could use Ron de Bruin approach: [Find last row, column or last cell](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm)

Answer (score 5):

try,

```
Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("Table1[#All]").Select
'or,
Worksheets("Sheet3").ListObjects("Table1").Range.Select
```

Comment: Why no explanations in the answer? I thought just as questions needs to be clear, answers needs to be as well. :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your table always starts in `B2` and has always a width of 4 columns you could use something like this to get the lastrow over all 4 columns:

```
Function getlastrow() As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    getlastrow = 0
    With Worksheets("YourWorksheet")
        For i = 0 To 3
            'starting with 2+i=2 (column B) and End with 2+i=5 (column E)
            If (.Cells(.Rows.Count, 2 + i).End(xlUp).Row) > getlastrow Then 
                getlastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2 + i).End(xlUp).Row
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Function
```

With this information you can set your range:

```
Sub SetRange()
    Dim myrange As Range
    With Worksheets("Tabelle1")
        Set myrange = .Range("B2:E" & getlastrow)
    End With
End Sub
```