# How to Delete Everything in an Excel Sheet Except for a Table?

Tags: excel, vba

I have many worksheets of messy data because of converting PDFs to Excel.

I select a piece of the worksheet and define it as a table called "GP_Data".

I am trying to delete everything in the worksheet except for the table I have defined.

I tried the below based on an answer I saw here, but seem to have a type mismatch because GP_Data is my Table Name.  I think VBA does not like a Table being defined as a Range.

```vb
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xCell As Range
Dim xAddress As String
        
xAddress = Application.ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
    
Set xRg = GP_Data
    
For Each xCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If Intersect(xCell, xRg) Is Nothing Then
        xCell.Clear
    End If
Next
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48316275/excel-vba-select-range-of-a-table/48317131) is how to select the range of the table. You might need to construct the range to clear using Range.Union.

Comment: `Set xRg = Range(GP_Data)` or `Set xRg = Range("GP_Data")` depending on whether `GP_Data` is a variable or literally the name of your table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Clear Cells Outside of a Table

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub deleteExceptTable()
    
    Dim urg As Range: Set urg = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Dim trg As Range: Set trg = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("GP_Data").Range

    Dim drg As Range
    Dim lSize As Long
    Dim cCount As Long
    
    ' Left
    lSize = trg.Column - urg.Column
    If lSize > 0 Then
        Set drg = urg.Columns(1).Resize(, lSize)
    End If
    ' Right
    cCount = urg.Column + urg.Columns.Count - trg.Column - trg.Columns.Count
    If cCount > 0 Then
        Set drg = CombinedRange(drg, _
            urg.Columns(lSize + trg.Columns.Count + 1).Resize(, cCount))
    End If
    
    Dim rCount As Long
    
    ' Top
    rCount = trg.Row - urg.Row
    If rCount > 0 Then
        Set drg = CombinedRange(drg, _
            Cells(urg.Row, trg.Column).Resize(rCount, trg.Columns.Count))
    End If
    ' Bottom
    rCount = urg.Row + urg.Rows.Count - trg.Row - trg.Rows.Count
    If rCount > 0 Then
        Set drg = CombinedRange(drg, Cells(trg.Row + trg.Rows.Count, _
            trg.Column).Resize(rCount, trg.Columns.Count))
    End If
    
    If Not drg Is Nothing Then
        drg.Clear
    End If

End Sub

Function CombinedRange( _
    ByVal BuiltRange As Range, _
    ByVal AddRange As Range) _
As Range
    If BuiltRange Is Nothing Then
        Set CombinedRange = AddRange
    Else
        Set CombinedRange = Union(BuiltRange, AddRange)
    End If
End Function
```