# Best VBA approach for finding table boundaries

Tags: excel, vba

Are there any downsides to using VBA Range.CurrentRegion to discern/select a table's boundaries?  I am working with a code base that uses .End(xlUp) and .End(xlLeft) approach advocated in the answers on this thread:

[excel vba select range of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48316275/excel-vba-select-range-of-a-table)

CurrentRegion appears more robust for dealing with individual blank cells in an individual table column or row. My code base does not use named tables currently. Just thought I would seek community advice before I refactor to CurrentRegion approach.

Comment: If you are sure that there are no empty rows or empty columns then I always recommend using `currentRegion`, but using tabels/ListObjects is definitly the way to go (if possible)

Comment: Thanks.  I think I'm going to refactor to currentRegion

Answer (score 0):

If it's really a `Table` then you should use the ListObject.

```
debug.print ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Address
```

You can find the whole list here: https://jkp-ads.com/Articles/Excel2007TablesVBA.asp
and here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject

The main drawback of CurrentRegion is when humans leave a space (or other similar garbage) in an adjacent cell.